Roast my schematic
Hobbyist here. As I'm self-taught and far from a daily designer, I'm curious about any input you might have regarding my newest creation:

My intention is to track the capacitance of whatever is connected to J3 (less than 500nF) and transmit the result to the differential bus at J4. J1 is the supply connector intended for a single lithium cell.
During measurement and transmission I expect about 10 mA of current draw, before going dormant (power-down mode) and only requiring a few uA.
I have built and tested the "measurement" part on a breadboard (pleasantly shocked as to how well the theory of capacitance and time constants holds up in reality!), so I'm rather confident there.
I haven't yet implemented or tested the RS485 part yet, but my only suspicion is it might not be the best idea to turn off the interface chip using a low-side switch during dormancy. Can't put my finger on to how this might come to bite me though - I hope it's fine after all :)
The power supply part (lower left) is mostly copy-pasting the catch-all from the QX2303 datasheet (component values not optimized yet). I haven't used or even ordered the chip yet and am open to further suggestions on how to get some stable 5 volts at around 10 mA.
Pretty sure there's some issues I can't see myself (isn't it always too few capacitors?), and I'm fully prepared to be roasted, so please don't hold back!

Well done on your use of ground & power symbols instead of the rats-nest of power supply wiring which many noobs make! ;)

Instead of trying to de-power your RS485 transceiver, you might consider using a SP483 instead. It has a 10uA low-power shutdown mode (activated by pulling DE low and /RE high), so instead of typing those pins together you would drive them separately.

@brhans Been there, done that ratsnest stuff though, still thanks for the observation :) ~ #SP483: I don't think I can spare another I/O to drive DE and /RE separately though?

Do you need to use /RE? What are you trying to receive?

@Ryan an "ack" from the main bus master

Another option would be to tie that GPIO directly to DE and create a branch with an inverter going to /RE.

Do not switch ground for U3!

It would be better to use a high side switch on the SP485CN. You could get unintended consequences by connecting it to VCC only as current could spill out of the pins with the ground in high impedance. (all pins could go to 5V worst case), unless the part is rated for it, use a high side switch.

Any recommendations for a suitable switch please? I really despise picking MOSFETs :D

I found IRLML2244: https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlml2244pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535664bfff25f0 ~ how does that datasheet tell me if the component suits my needs or not?

what about BSS83P? https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/BSS83P_Rev1%206.pdf?fileId=5546d46147a9c2e40147f7eba9ec0a51

The SP485 has a minimum supply voltage of 4.75V. The maximum short circuit output current is 250mA (the supply current consumed inside the chip is <1mA), so the maximum allowable Rds(on) is a convenient 1Ω. Give yourself a hefty 50% design factor and you're looking for a logic level P-channel MOSFET with a Rds(on) of <  500mΩ at Vgs = -5V which should be...almost all of them.

To de-energize an IC, always use a high-side switch (disconnecting VCC) rather than a low-side (Ground). Disconnecting the ground can compromise the quality of the ground connection when the IC is powered, and when it's unpowered, all pins may float at the supply voltage.
Even when disconnecting VCC to power down the IC, ensure that all GPIOs from the MCU leading into the IC (or any other input sources on different pins) are grounded. If not, the IC may power itself through these input pins via the internal ESD protection diodes.

The CPU pins must not be grounded, it is enough to put them to output-low.

@datenheim , setting the GPIOs to output-low is a way to ground the pins! Obviously in a dynamic scenario like this I was not suggesting that the pins be permanently grounded in hardware, but grounded through software control.  The key point is that when an IC is powered down by disconnection of VCC, all of the connected GPIOs must be set to ground potential to avoid unintended power-up paths.

Yes. "Must be grounded" is a bit ambiguous :) So we are on par.

You have many assumptions incorrect and the design may not work because of them, and the chips may get damaged as well.
First of all, the ground side switching of a chip with data connections to MCU is the first thing you should definitely not do. As soon as you turn off the FET, any IO pin that goes low such as the combined DE/RE will act as the chip ground through protection diodes.
It also makes the RS-485 side lose ground reference and may disturb the bus.
It also seems you are assuming that the RS-485 bus is a two-wire bus and will work without ground reference. But it's not a two-wire bus, it's a bus with two data wires that must have a shared ground reference with other RS-485 chips on the bus, and if no other ground reference is between them, you need a common ground wire between them.
Also the 10mA current draw when transmitting is likely not true. RS-485 buses are usally terminated with 120 ohm resistors at the two ends of the bus. Including them and the other RS-485 devices loading the bus, the load will be less than 60 ohms. Assuming 60 ohms, current to drive 5V into 60 ohms is already more than 80mA. In reality, driver only needs to drive 1.5V into 54 ohms, or 28mA.
